# What is the meaning of "stand one's ground"?

Tags: meaning

At about 40 seconds into [this video](https://www.facebook.com/StealthyFreedom/videos/1053025724711521/), the reporter says (as I can discern it) "Several of the women stood at their ground and were stabbed as they chanted slogans..." My impression is the "stood at their ground" part means that women did not retreat when aggressors wanted to suppress them. Nevertheless, the presenter's accent is British and I am not sure what he means.

Answer (score 5):

There is no preposition *at* in the sentence.

> Several of the women **who** stood their ground **with considerable courage** were stabbed as they
>   chanted slogans for equal rights.

To [stand one's ground](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stand-your-ground) is an idiom:

> **to ​refuse to be ​pushed ​backwards**, or to ​continue in ​your ​beliefs
>   in an ​argument.

[Cambridge Dictionaries Online]